# how to remove padding-top in menu drop-down react-select?

Tags: reactjs, react-select

how to remove padding-top in menu drop-down react-select?

```
const customStyles = {

    indicatorSeparator: styles => ({ ...styles, display: "none" }),
    option: (provided, state) => ({
      ...provided,
      fontSize: 16,

        height:"40px",
      paddingLeft: "11px",
      ":firstChild": {
        margin: "10px",
        padding: "10px",
        borderRadius: "10px 10px 10px 10px"

    }),



 <Select
    styles={customStyles}
    defaultValue={[colourOptions[2], colourOptions[3]]}
    isMulti
    name="colors"
    options={colourOptions}
    className="basic-multi-select"
    classNamePrefix="select"
  />
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uHO8N.png)
https://codesandbox.io/s/react-codesandboxer-example-90zz6

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should set the styles for the `menuList` style key according to react-select [docs](https://react-select.com/styles).

```
menuList: (provided, state) => ({
   ...provided,
   paddingTop: 0,
   paddingBottom: 0,
}),
```

Comment: thanks, I just could not see the class because the list closes

Comment: me neither, but in Chrome I can press "Ctrl + Shift + C" to select elements, which doesn't trigger blur events on focused elements. Than I could easily hover over the element and see it's class name.

Comment: React-select is using `emotion`, achieving your goal with css class is an anti-pattern. You should keep using `styles` props

Comment: @Laura you are right.
I updated my answer to use the customizable styles of react-select

Answer (score 9):

The default `margin-top` between the menu list and the select box can be removed easily with the props `styles` like this:

```
const styles = {
  menu: base => ({
    ...base,
    marginTop: 0
  })
}
```

Live [example here](https://codesandbox.io/s/stackoverflow-answer-57309191-7thu0).

Answer (score 1):

use this use multi  inline style  by using {[firststyle,secandstyle]}
and define the second style bellow the first style as shape following

```
 `const nopadinng={
      paddingTop:0};`

and remove  the classname

    // remove the className 
        className="basic-multi-select"


    const nopadinng={
      paddingTop:0};
            styles={[customStyles,nopadinng]}
```