# How to remove the padding top and bottom in menu drop-down react-select?

Tags: reactjs, react-select

I have tried this based on the answers given here: [how to remove padding-top in menu drop-down react-select?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57309191/how-to-remove-padding-top-in-menu-drop-down-react-select). But this doesn't work for me. The space is also bigger than most examples found on https://react-select.com/styles. It sucks that I can't inspect element the drop-down to see what is going wrong.

My code:

```
const stateOptions = [
     { value: 'All', label: 'ALL' },
      { value: 'SELECT1', label: 'SELECT1' },
      { value: 'SELECT2', label: 'SELECT2' },
      { value: 'SELECT3', label: 'SELECT3' }
  ]

  const options = [
    {
      options: stateOptions
    }
  ]

  const customStyles = {
    menu: provided => ({
      ...provided,
      marginTop: 0,
      width: '100%',
      marginTop: '-1px',
      
    }),
    menuList: (provided, state) => ({
      ...provided,
      paddingTop: 0,
      paddingBottom: 0,
      overflow: 'hidden',
    }),
    option: (provided, state) => ({
      ...provided,
      height: '55px',
      borderBottom: '1px solid #b0b0b0',
      color: state.isSelected ? 'white' : '#000000',
      background: state.isSelected ? '#e3155c' : 'white',
      fontFamily: 'Qanelas-Regular',
      fontSize: '16px',
      padding: '15px',
      ':hover': {
        ...provided[':active'],
        backgroundColor: '#e3155c',
        color: 'white'
      },
    }),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What really worked for me is the following:

```
group: provided => ({
  ...provided,
  paddingTop: 0,
}),
```

A hack to try to inspect the code is to press `F8` in order to pause the script execution.

Comment: Thanks, why does paddingTop also removes the space beneath? Nice tip about the F8 btw!

Comment: that's weird, just noticed that.

Comment: ok got it. check my updated answer. i forgot to clone the already set values/properties with spread operator.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Wish they expanded the documentation a bit more so the style keys make more sense